# Check passed data with a view is not empty in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 and I want to pass a data with a view.
I have used this code in a controller.

```
$view = View::make('settings.editEvent');
$view->bounderyData = $bounderyData;
```

And I want to check whether this data exists or not in the view settings/editEvent.blade.php

Tried using this..

```
<script>
   if('{{$bounderyData.length()}}'!=null)
      console.log('exists');
</script>
```

Error :

```
Array to string conversion error
```

How can I check the existence ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign the data to the View variable, but instead, pass it along using `with` as Laravel requests you to use:

```
$view = View::make('settings.editEvent')
    ->with('bounderyData', $bouderyData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually both of the snippets work the same way. You can either pass data using `with()` method or by assigning it to view as property. So it doesn't really matter. But it looks like you are using some weird syntax because you are trying to access method `length()` using dot syntax inside Blade echo statement. Try:

```
if({{count($bounderyData)}}!=null)
  console.log('exists');
```

or something similar. Remember that everything inside `{{}}` is going to be echo'ed by PHP. So if you have some sort of array there you may either want to count number of elements or maybe cast it to JSON and then decode it inside Javascript. If you still have problem, let us know what is the issue.